# Spice cake has sweet crispy top

Tags: cake

I made a spice cake from scratch.  I've made it before, this time I made cupcakes.  The cake was perfect, but the top was crunchy and sweet with little holes.  Was the butter not incorporated enough and fried the sugar into a sweet top?

Comment: When you made it as cupcakes did you change anything? Baking temp or time? The recipe might help, too.

Comment: I changed the timing since they were smaller cupcakes in the little cardboard containers rather than paper cups. The cake was moist on the inside so they weren't overcooked.  I will add the recipe when I don't have to get to work!  :)

Answer (score 2):

German Apple Cake also responds like this. Must say that I've come to adore the crunchy top! :) But yes, you are right, it doesn't really happen if you bake it as a large cake. It's mostly just along the outer edge of the cake, in my case anyway.

My reasoning is that cupcakes contain less batter per surface area exposed to the oven... I think the oven just caramelizes the sugar in the batter. Think of meringue where the sugar isn't properly incorporated... you see little holes in the surface of the meringue. I'm not saying you should dissolve the sugar better in this cake recipe, but if the crunchy (slightly holey top) isn't desirable for you, try using caster sugar which dissolves easier.